# UICollectionView not loading Image from SDWebImage

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uiimage, sdwebimage

I created a `UICollectionView` Inside a `ViewController` but the `UICollectionView` is not loading the data I appended to the array. I tried to print from the `UIcollectionView` datasource and delegate but it also not printing

```
 import UIKit
 import Alamofire
 import SwiftyJSON
 import SDWebImage

 class SelectCarViewController: UIViewController,  UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

  @IBOutlet weak var selectedcarManufacturalLebel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var selectedcarPlateNumber: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var selectCarCarouselCollectionView:  UICollectionView!

  var selecrCarsURL = "https://my.api.mockaroo.com/cars.json?key=86f86980"
  var selectCarArray : [SelectCarDataModel] = [SelectCarDataModel]()
  let selectCarFromJSON = SelectCarDataModel()


   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    selectCarCarouselCollectionView.delegate = self
    selectCarCarouselCollectionView.dataSource = self
    //register custom sell nib file
    selectCarCarouselCollectionView.register(UINib.init(nibName: "SelectCarViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "selectIdentifier")

    //Add flowyout function
    addFlowlayOut()

    getselectCarData(url: selecrCarsURL)
    selectCarCarouselCollectionView.reloadData()
   }

   //MARK:- Add carousel flowlayout for viewcontroller collectionview
   func addFlowlayOut() {
    let flowlayout = UPCarouselFlowLayout()
    flowlayout.itemSize = CGSize(width:   UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width - 60, height:    selectCarCarouselCollectionView.frame.size.height)

    flowlayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    flowlayout.sideItemScale = 0.8
    flowlayout.sideItemAlpha = 1.0
    flowlayout.spacingMode = .fixed(spacing: 5.0)
    selectCarCarouselCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = flowlayout


}

   //MARK:- Select Car Newtworking
   func getselectCarData(url: String) {
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .get).responseJSON {
        response in
        if response.result.isSuccess {
            print("Sucess Got the Selected Cars Data")

            let selelectCarJSON : JSON =   JSON(response.result.value!)

            print(selelectCarJSON)

            self.updateSelectedCar(json: selelectCarJSON)

        }else {
            print("error)")
        }
        }
      }

    //MARK:- Select Car Update JSON Parsing
    func updateSelectedCar(json : JSON) {

    //for i in 0...json.count-1 {
    selectCarFromJSON.image = json["car"][0]["img"].stringValue
    selectCarFromJSON.carType = json["car"][0] ["manufacturer"].stringValue
    selectCarFromJSON.carModel = json["car"][0]["model"].stringValue


    print("this is it \(selectCarFromJSON.image)")

    //}

    }
   //MARK: -- UICollection Delegate and Datasourse Manipulation

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return selectCarArray.count
    }

      func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = selectCarCarouselCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "selectIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! SelectCarViewCell

    let selectCar = SelectCarDataModel()
    selectCar.image = selectCarFromJSON.image
    selectCar.carType = selectCarFromJSON.carType
    selectCar.carModel = selectCarFromJSON.carModel

    selectCarArray.append(selectCar)

    print(selectCarArray)

    cell.selectCarImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: selectCarArray[indexPath.row].image))
    selectedcarManufacturalLebel.text = selectCarArray[indexPath.row].carType
    selectedcarPlateNumber.text = selectCarArray[indexPath.row].carModel

    print("this is cell\(selectCarArray[indexPath.row].image)")

    selectCarCarouselCollectionView.reloadData()
    return cell

    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,  didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print(indexPath.row)

     }
   }
```

I expected the `SDWebImage` to get the URL from the `JSON` and populate the `UICollectionView`

Comment: why you are reloading data in your collection method ? Is this data coming from `cellForItemAt` this method??

Comment: @Wings I've removed it. it's still not working

Comment: reload your data in this `getselectCarData(url: String)` method

Comment: @Wings I just did. same problem.  even the print statement inside it isn't printing

Comment: Are you getting the data from server ??

Comment: @Wings Yes. I get a JSON reponse. which I see in my debug console. the problem is passing the JSON to UIImage and the other info to labels in the UICollectionView

Comment: you did a lot of mess in your code this could be very simpler check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28475389/alamofire-swift-in-uicollectionview and modify your code I am sure you will get your desired result

Answer (score 0):

SDWebImage show URL image in imageView not a local image.

your `selectCarArray` store an image not url. so it's not working.

try this:-

```
cell.selectCarImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: "https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/beautiful-abstract-grunge-decorative-navy-260nw-539880832.jpg"))
```